# ¿Convertir un objeto a array con clave y valor en JS?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

gracias por sus respuestas y comentarios esta vez acudo a ustedes por lo siguiente, tengo un objeto con la siguiente estructura:

```
const data = [
  {id: 1, genero: 'Masculino'},
  {id: 2, genero: 'Femenino'},
  {id: 3, genero: 'Indefinido'}
];
```

Quiero convertir ese array de objetos a un array con la siguiente estructura:

```
const data2 = [
  "genero: Masculino",
  "genero: Femenino'",
  "genero: Indefinido"
];
```

Estoy intentado con el siguiente código:

```
for (const [key, value] in Object.entries(data)) {
  data2.push((`${key}: ${value}`));
}
```

De ante mano les agradezco sus respuestas y comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es un arreglo de strings como el ejemplo que pones lo que podrias usar es [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) de esta manera:

```javascript
// Obtiene los valores de los objetos y se obtiene el valor de la propieda genero, 
// despues se retorna un string con el valor de la propiedad

Object.values(data).map(({ genero }) => (`genero: ${genero}`))
```

lo que retorta seria algo a lo que quieres:

```
[
  "genero: Masculino",
  "genero: Femenino'",
  "genero: Indefinido"
]
```

Si lo que quieres es un arreglo de objetos solo con la propiedad `genero` podrias hacerlo asi:

```javascript
data.map(({ genero}) => ({ genero }))
```

lo que retorna es algo asi:

```
[
  {genero: "Masculino"},
  {genero: "Femenino"},
  {genero: "Indefinido"}
]
```

Mas info de `.map()` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, que pasaria en caso de que en el objeto las claves no sean iguales es decir si tengo como clave genero: 'masculino', pero también existe puesto: 'Desarrollador' de nuevo muchas gracias por compartir tus conocimientos.